# The night artist

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

I draw in green in the sky,
Flashing lights, up high,
Holographic waves and flames,
Flick at the dark blue sky.

What am I?

Comment: @Shahriar Mahmud Sajid Unforunately I don't know who posted first. If someone knows please tell me

Comment: Hi, you can see the exact time of answering when you hover over the "answered x hours ago" with your mouse. :)  So for example, Shahriar Mahmud Sajid answered at 18:22:25, and I answered at 18:20:33.

Comment: Oh sorry, on my phone it said 1 hour for both

Comment: No worries! Keep up the good work, I love your puzzles! ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you maybe

> Aurora Borealis?
>  It is a natural light display in the Earth's sky (on the far north), that can be green among other colors. Also existing Aurora Australis (on the far south).

Comment: Can someone explain me why my answer is voted for deletion?

Comment: Sorry I don't see it

Answer (score 4):

> Probably Aurora or polar lights (northern light as in aurora borealis, southern light as in aurora australis), it is a green light in the sky looks like holographic waves and flames.